# Create filter in Jira to display available work

Tags: jira, jql

In Jira, there's the "Active Sprint" view. You can expand/collapse all User Stories and Bugs to see the Sub-Tasks (that need to be done in order to close the bug/user story).

I would like to have a (quick) filter there to see which Bugs or User Stories I can work on. The requirement is that ALL Sub-Tasks of the Bug / User Story are still open.

Is that possible at all? A solution with multiple filters using each other would be fine too.

UPDATE: In other words, the filter should remove all Bugs / User Stories, along with their Sub-Tasks, that have at least 1 Sub-Task, that is not "open"

Thanks!